# How to install a downloaded gdm theme to change my log in theme?

Tags: gnome, themes, login-screen, gdm

I have downloaded themes from https://www.gnome-look.org and I have changed applied the gtk themes and shell themes successfully. But I am facing a great difficulty in changing the log in screen. I know I have to paste the files somewhere and may be replace the default log in entry. But I got no specific solutions. All the solutions I found was videos and documentation of about 10-11 years ago. So, please help me someone.

Comment: what is your 0S? Can you share the link for the exact theme you would like to apply?

Comment: See if the gnome-look.org page for you theme has instructions below the screenshots. Normally they have.